# Creating a Runnable jar with optional parameters

Tags: java, jar

Curious little issue I am running into here:

I would like a client to be able to do something like:

(1) `java -jar myJar.jar inputFile outputFile`

or

(2) `java -jar myJar.jar text outputFile`

`outputFile` is an optional argument.

Essentially (1) will read input from a file for them, while (2) they provide the input my program will use directly. There is no way to determine whether or not the argument is the input or whether it is the location of the file though that I can think of. For normal command line stuff you would specify a flag like `-i inputfile` to show you want it to read from a file. What are my options here that maintain ease of use for the client?

Is my only option to create a syntax the client must use for the first argument? i.e.

`"-t text"` or `"-i inputFile"`?

I have seen libraries such as commons cli which would enable this, but I would prefer a solution that does not involve using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, can't you just check the number of arguments instead of explicitly specifying direct input? Like, if one arg is passed the first arg is output, and if 2 args are passed then the first arg is input and the second arg is output?

With that being said - Using a 'option' syntax of the hyphen- kind is probably easiest on most people used to a cli.

Comment: yeah figured I would be forced to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read from standard input (System.in) and print to standard out (System.out)

This way, no parameters are required. It's very intuitive for people who work with CLI tools. And you can leave the details of where the input comes from to the OS.

So in a unix OS, you would use your jar something like this:

```
echo "some test" | java -jar myjar.jar > outfile
```

or

```
cat somefile | java -jar myjar.jar > outfile
```

Comment: This jar will be executed by another program. The output of the program depends on the parameters provided. It could be nothing, or a textual output. I am not sure I understand how this helps with the possible parameter misunderstanding.

Comment: You're right, this suggestion does not solve your parameter problem. But it's a (imho better) alternative. Not to use parameters at all, but to pipe input to the program to the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
input=text or file=inputfile
```

(with output=outputFile as optional).

In this case, you can treat all your parameters in the same way and split them with the delimiter '=', check the left side of '=' to determine which parameter it is.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Cubic was faster though. upvoted anyway